# Filter ports allowed to connect to the server

Tags: python, sockets, security, ssl, tls1.2

Is there any way to filter (maybe some kind of a firewall?) the ports that are allowed to connect to a server, which is implemented using the package `socket` in Python?

I have a server running on port `1080` and would like it to only accept client connections from the `localhost`'s ports in range `10000-11000`. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Just bind it to `127.0.0.1`, which rules out all other IP addresses, and then, if you must, check the client port of each accepted socket via `getpeername()` and close the socket if you don't like it. But you don't want to do the second part of this, because it implies special coding in the client to only use ports 10000-11000, which is tedious and error-prone. There is no good reason for such a rule.

Comment: That's a good way to do it. However, if I accept all the connections by default and then close the socket if I don't like the client's port, would leave the server vulnerable to DoS attacks. But there doesn't seem a better way to do it.

Comment: It's only vulnerable to DOS attacks from within the same host. If that's your problem you won't solve it with software. But you shold forget about checking the ports. It adds no value.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne I am simulating different networks on the same host. To better separate them I wanted to use port ranges, e.g. network A can only use ports in the range 10000-11000, network B in the range 20000-21000, and so on. So if someone wants to connect to my gateway running on port 9999, I first have to check from which network it is coming from and only accept the connection if the network is trusted or whitelisted. I don't know if you understand what I mean, but this is just a simulation and won't be used in any real-life scenario. But I thank you for your clarification nonetheless.

Comment: The way to simulate different subnets is by using different subnets. Ports have nothing to do with it. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the `Socket` module documentation, `You can receive information about the remote socket with this command:`
[image]

The `Socket` module documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#creating-sockets

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this would require the server to accept the connection first and then close the socket if he doesn't like the client's port. Is there a better way to do it, so that the server doesn't even have to accept the connection in the first place. Like setting up a firewall so only the desired client ports can reach the server's port?